# Google login get access token with new GoogleSignInOptions

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-play-services, google-signin, google-oauth

My android app currently uses the GoogleAuthUtil to signin users and fetch an `access_token` which is passed to the backend (code snippets below which show creating the GoogleApiClient and using GoogleAuthUtil to get the token).

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(Plus.API)
        .addScope(new Scope("profile"))
        .build();
...
...

String accessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(GoogleLoginActivity.this,
                            Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient),
                            "oauth2:profile email");
```

which I then sent to the backend

I am now trying to move to the new Google SignIn - https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

and so changed the GoogleApiClient creation like,

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestEmail()
        .requestIdToken("<web client id>")
        .build();
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .enableAutoManage(this, this)
        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
        .build();
```

and then to do the login use,

```
startActivityForResult(Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient), RC_GET_TOKEN);
```

and on activity result use (similar to the example in the link above),

```
OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
if (opr.isDone()) {
    // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
    // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
    Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
    handleSignInResult(opr.get());
} else {
    // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
    // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
    // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
    showProgress();
    opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
            hideProgress();
            handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
        }
    });
}
```

but now it seems that in `handleSingInResult(GoogleSignInResult result)` I can only get an `id token` back with
`result.getSignInAccount().getIdToken();`

Does anyone know if it is possible to get an access token from this (like previously) and if so how? Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same issue here, have you managed to work your way around this issue?

Comment: Not really. Had to implement id token handling in the backend before I could start using this.

Comment: I ended up using Android's account picker to get the account name, and the GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Context, accoutName, scope) to retrieve the token itself, it worked like a charm and a lot simpler then the first approuch.

Comment: I considered doing that myself initially but then realized that there was lot less code and error paths in the app to deal with (related to using the GoogleApiClient `connect()` etc.) if I just added idToken parsing to the backend.

Answer (score 6):

After signing in you'll be able to get the token:

```
final String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mAppContext, mAccountName, AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE);
```

dont forget to do it an Asynctask. for more detail have a look at [here](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/2531cbdbe27e5795eb78bf47d27e8c1be494aad4/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/util/LoginAndAuthHelper.java)

**EDIT:**

Note that, despite the method name:

```
GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()
```

it does not give you an OAuth Token, it rather returns a "short-lived authorization code" according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth).

> What I should do after getting the Authorization Code by calling the
>   GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() ?

You should transmit the Authorization Code to your backend server over HTTPS. Only from your server you should attempt to receive Access and/or Refresh token, not in your app.

Comment: @aberdfar , this method is deprecated

Answer (score 2):

So i was having the same problem. they have changed it now so the token comes through in

```
GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult2: "+acct.getIdToken());
```

To get access too this token you have too ask for it in

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail().requestProfile().requestId().requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_ID))
                    .build();
```

The `R.string.server_client_ID` is the `client ID` from the project that you make in your Google developer Console.

I hope this helps you.

here is also the documentation i followed. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth

Comment: as I mentioned in my question, the token received this way is an `id_token` and not an `access_token`. So for now it looks like we still need to fetch the `access_token` the same way as before with the `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()` in an AsyncTask (I was kind of hoping there would be another way but anyway...)

Comment: That's correct. id_token need to be exchanged for access_token.

Comment: Please correct me, but it seems that id_token can't be exchanged to access_token. id_token contains user info encoded inside the token itself. If you want to get access_token, you need to request for server Auth code (`getServerAuthCode`). This is unfortunate, because when you request for server Auth code, Google notify user that the app request "Work Offline".